# How to use image coordinates from photoshop in imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick, photoshop, imagick, distortion

I am trying to distort image to make it look as much realistic on the T-Shirt as it can. I can make it in photoshop look amazing, but I am having problem in actually transforming it using imagemagick into actual code and than making it look same as it looks on photoshop on my website.

We are adding images on T-shirts mockup through Admin panel where distortion for final customer or viewer of the website takes the most important part of our product as it is an ecommerce site.

I am attaching two photos to show you the actual problem, these are the photos from Adobe Photoshop, and I am looking for help to let me know if anyone had experience with this how I can take this exact code from image distortion from photoshop and use it for imagemagick metods to actually make it the same on my website.

Here is some of the code we are using:

$process55 = new Process('convert '.$path.'/image/ms_displaced_logo.png -matte -virtual-pixel transparent -distort Perspective "0,0,0,0 0,1342,0,1300 1899,0,1700,0 1899,1342,1850,1300" '.$path.'/image/ms_displaced_logo_distort.png');

```
       $process55->run();
       if (!$process5->isSuccessful()) {
           throw new ProcessFailedException($process55);
       }
       echo $process55->getOutput();
       echo '<img src="\image\ms_displaced_logo_distort.png">';
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: You need to add links to your 2 photos, so we can see what you have. As a new member, you do not have permission to upload photos. So upload them to some free hosting service and put the links in a comment or your post, whichever you can do. How are you distorting the the image in Photoshop? Are you using a simple warp or the puppet warp?  If the latter, ImageMagick does not have that kind of warping.

Comment: What is your question about ImageMagick? What does not work?

Comment: If you are interested, you may contact me about my tshirt script. You can find it at http://www.fmwconcept.com/imagemagick

Comment: @fmw42 
The question is how to actually distort image to look the same way how it looks in Adobe Photoshop? When you see photos, it will be easier for you to understand. Now, we are able to distort the perspective by using just 4 dots on the angles of the image, which doesn't curve outlines of the photo to distort it correctly.

I am not able to open your link.

Thanks for reaching out!

Comment: Sorry about my link. http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick should work. See https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/#perspective for 4 point perspective in ImageMagick. See https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/#control_points for how the coordinates are ordered as input-output pairs.  Where are your images? You still have not posted them. Upload to some free hosting service and put the links in a comment.

Comment: It doesn't let me to add link in my comment :( Works now?
https://ibb.co/n3J2Nqb
https://ibb.co/HC91jnn

Comment: That is wrapped too much around her body to be done by simple image processing that uses a distortion map from shading. If her body was not turned so much, one might get a reasonable result.

Comment: So does that mean that imagemagick can't make that kind of distortion?

Comment: It cannot wrap the image around the backside of her body. If you can do it in Photoshop with a simple perspective distortion and distortion from shading, then you likely can do it with ImageMagick. I would have to see exactly what you are doing in Photoshop to know for sure because Photoshop has some complex processing that ImageMagick cannot do. Look at the examples from my tshirt script. That is what ImageMagick can do.

Comment: I understand. I will explain you in words:
1. I place background image (In this case girl)
2. I create a new layer on top of the T-shirt with design I want to apply and I place it where I want it.
3. I duplicate the background image with the model and put it on the top of everything. I cut the square in the t-shirt to make like a "mask" with this layer, because of the printing area in my printing company.
4. Than I press "CTRL+T" to transform the design layer and use "Warp" to curve edges to follow the model's figure.

Comment: 5. Last, I cut the square of the T shirt in a new layer, put it on the top of the design layer, convert it to black and white, give it a little bit of contrast and volume up brightnes and after I convert it to "Hard light" blending mode, it gives a beautiful shadow and lightening effect.

I will upload a video on youtube later today so I can show you.

Comment: Did you do that in Photoshop or ImageMagick?

Comment: I did this in Photoshop, but the process is pretty much same in Imagemagick. Only hard part is to distort image by curving sides of the photo (Warp)

Comment: How did you curve the sides in Photoshop?  Was it from another distortion or from the distortion from the shading?

Comment: Here is the video showing the process - https://youtu.be/MCOZtoe3e90 (It is uploading right now, will be live in like 15 minutes)

Comment: ImageMagick can do everything you do, except the Photoshop warp. My tshirt script does all that, except it uses a rectangle and does not do the perspective. But it could do that, since ImageMagick supports perspective transforms. My script even allows for a mask.